# NMAKE static link errors

Tags: qt, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, nmake

I am trying to build the static version of Qt and i am currently running into an issue with NMAKE (I think).

Part of the build process [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html) states that I should run the following command:

```
configure -debug -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -opensource
```

when i run the command i get the following error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libucrt.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.EXE"' : return code '0x450'
Stop.
```

Previous to this i had an error about missing corecrt.h so i added the following to the make file to sort that error out.

```
set CL=/I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt"
```

I know that the files i need are located at:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
```

But i am unsure on how to let link.exe know about them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your command line build environment is not set up properly. Starting from a clean cmd (win-r, cmd, enter), show all steps that go from opening the prompt to building, assuming an empty build folder being the cd.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out i was having problems with the prefix being incorrectly set so going back to the first command it was modified to the following:

```
configure -debug -nomake examples -nomake tests -skip qtwebengine -opensource -static -prefix C:\QT\qt-everywhere-src-5.10.1 -redo -recheck-all
```

Where the argument after -prefix is the build location (in my case this is the same as the source directory)

Thanks for your help